# Shorten URL in MVC to action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I'm trying to shorten a URL from:`http://localhost:50830/Controller/Action/{parameter}`
To: `http://localhost:50830/{parameter}`

So the second URL has to do the same thing as the first URL.
I already tried this in the `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
name: "Parameter route",
url: "{parameter}",
defaults: new { controller = "controllerName",
                action = "Actionname",
                parameter = UrlParameter.Optional  });
```

But then when I type this URL form `http://localhost:50830/{parameter}` into the browser, it says `The resource cannot be found`.

Comment: Confirm 2 things: 1. make sure there is a `controllerNameController` and a `Actionname` Action exist in the controller. 2. make sure the route you listed is above the default route.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you can try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{param}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then ensure that this is the first route in your RouteConfig.cs file and also that you have a HomeController class with an action like:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string param)
    {
        ...
    }
```